# Accessing getValueState for all page elements

Tags: sapui5

I need to access the `valueState` property of a list times.

In my view, the four times, are displayed, one set for each day. The information is provided in the Model.

```js
var storeModel = new JSONModel({
    EffectiveDateFrom: this._selectedEffectiveDateFrom,
    SiteInfo: oModelData,
    SplitShifts: false,
    OpeningTimes: [{
        BusinesDay: "Sunday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:00",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }, {
        BusinesDay: "Monday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:00",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }, {
        BusinesDay: "Tuesday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:00",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }, {
        BusinesDay: "Wednesday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:30",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }, {
        BusinesDay: "Thursday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:00",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }, {
        BusinesDay: "Friday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:00",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }, {
        BusinesDay: "Saturday",
        startTime1: "08:00",
        endTime1: "18:00",
        startTime2: "",
        endTime2: "",
        isOpen: true,
        tradingHours: "10:00",
        overNight: false
    }]
});
```

```xml
<cells>
  <ObjectIdentifier title="{store>BusinesDay}" />
  <TimePicker id="TP1_1" value="{store>startTime1}" valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm" change="onTimeChangedOpening" visible="{store>isOpen}" placeholder="Enter Opening Time" />
  <TimePicker id="TP1_2" value="{store>endTime1}" valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm" change="onTimeChangedClosing" visible="{store>isOpen}" placeholder="Enter Closing Time" />
  <TimePicker id="TP1_11" value="{store>startTime2}" valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm" change="onTimeChangedOpeningSplit" visible="{store>isOpen}" placeholder="Enter Opening time" />
  <TimePicker id="TP1_21" value="{store>endTime2}" valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm" change="onTimeChangedClosingSplit" visible="{store>isOpen}" placeholder="Enter Closing time" />
  <CheckBox id="closedChkSunday" value="{store>isOpen}" select="toggleOpenClosed" />
  <Text text="{store>tradingHours}" visible="{store>isOpen}" editable="false" />
</cells>
```

I can set the value state to error when I am accessing the individual component:

```js
oViewComponent.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success);
```

How do I check all the time fields for an error in one go using `getValueState`?

Answer (score 2):

It might not be beautiful but you could query the [message model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.message.MessageModel.html) if you are using the [MessageManager](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b8c4e534cdb440e9a5bbff86f9572bd6.html)

To use the `MessageManager` you have to [register](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.message.MessageManager.html#registerObject) the controls or a whole view at the `MessageManager`. Perhaps you've done that already?

```js
sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().registerObject(this.getView(), true);
```

Then you can retrieve the `MessageModel` from the `MessageManager`. The `MessageModel` contains all Messages. Each message that has a `target` property is associated with a specific property of a specific control. The `target` property contains a string in the following format: `controlId/property`. As your view will not be the only one registered at the `MessageManager`, you have to filter the messages from the `MessageModel`.

```js
var messagesModelMessages = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().getMessageModel().getProperty("/");
var viewPrefix = this.getView().getId() + "--";
if ($.isArray(messagesModelMessages)) {
    messagesModelMessages.forEach(function (message) {
        if (message.target && message.target.startsWith(viewPrefix)) {
            // the message is pointing to a control in this view
            var controlId = message.target.split("/")[0];
            var control = sap.ui.getCore().byId(controlId);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @hirse how does the target get set in the message? Does the parser automatically use the binding path to determine the target ID and property?

Comment: @Kyle, I didn't write this answer, maybe schnoedel could help?

Comment: @Kyle, the MessageManager consumes the validation events. The [validationError event](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#event:validationError) has the source control and source property as arguments. When the user enters an invalid value, the sap.ui.model.Type of the twoway binding raises an ValidationException. [That exception will be caught by the Control (ManagedObject) and the validationError event is fired instead](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.48/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L3155).